# Wix componentGroupRef unresolved symbol, but naming seems to be okay

Tags: wix

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="1" Version="1.0.0.0" Language="1033" Name="My Application Name" Manufacturer="My Manufacturer Name">
        <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="My Application Name"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <!-- Step 2: Add files to your installer package -->
        <!-- Copied from output from heat.exe -->
        <Fragment>
            <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
                <Directory Id="dirBF6284DAE096656A1A0B06AE3DCAA0C9" Name="MyAppName">
                    <Component Id="cmp26BABDEF350D4D06E3894ED92A9EA86E" Guid="8E1DA6FE-08EA-4D2E-8EBA-85131387A359">
                        <File Id="filEBD2DA63132D753815D44CEDC2ED5E88" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\benutzer.csv" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </DirectoryRef>
        </Fragment>            
        <Fragment>
            <ComponentGroup Id="MyComponentGroup">
                <ComponentRef Id="cmp26BABDEF350D4D06E3894ED92A9EA86E" />
            </ComponentGroup>
        </Fragment>


        <!-- Step 3: Tell WiX to install the files -->
        <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyComponentGroup" />
        </Feature>

    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Error:

```
error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol ’Component:MyComponentGroup’ in section ’Product:*’.
```

I reduced the full code for this example, normally I would have many more files to be packaged. The component harvesting is done by heat.exe, I copied the components part into this wix file.
Although the error indicates what is the problem, I don't know what exactly to look for.

The code is run from a bat-file:

```
set WIX_BIN=c:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\
echo Wix Toolset Bin Path: %WIX_BIN%
"%WIX_BIN%candle.exe" out.wxs -ext WixUtilExtension
if exist out.wixobj (
"%WIX_BIN%light.exe" -out out.msi out.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension
)
pause
```

Comment: You should replace `UpgradeCode="1"` with `UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE"` if you don't want to publish your GUID. Otherwise it's just confusing because it looks like another error in the script. In addition, the `Fragment` element is not allowed under `Product`.

Comment: Having said that, the actual reason for the error seems to be that your candle command-line is missing the .wxs file from the Heat output. The light command-line is missing the related .wixobj file too.

Comment: I did copy the fragment part of heat.exe's output by hand, manually. I could not figure out how to automate it, there are so few examples and the documentation is not really helpful either. I managed to get it working by removing the `fragment` tags whilst keeping their content.

Comment: It's not required to copy anything by hand. Just add output file of heat.exe to the candle.exe command-line, e. g. `candle.exe out.wxs out_from_heat.wxs` and `light.exe out.wixobj out_from_heat.wixobj`. I can turn that into a full answer with examples if you like.